# T-SQL - create partition function and scheme - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I am creating partition function and schemes.

In SQL Server 2008, it only defines range partitioning and not list partitions.

Dont we have list partitioning in SQL Server?

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no List Partitioning in SQL Server 2008. But you can fake it into creating one using the LEFT clause.

Read up here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/partition/64740/

Comment: AFAIK Hash Partitioning is not implemented in SQL 2008.

Comment: It was originally planned (syntax for it existed in the early betas) but it was dropped halfway through the beta period.  Wish I could share details on why.